# How to get all users with active Commerce 2 subscription

Tags: templating, craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, query, plugin-craftcommerce2

How do I get all the users with an active subscription in Commerce 2? I want to be able to filter entries by subscribed users.

Comment: Is this in the CMS or on the front end?

Comment: @JasonMayo front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a simple plugin.

```
use craft\db\Query;

class MyPluginVariable
{
      public function allActivelySubscribedUserIds()
      {
           $subscribedUserIds = (new Query())
                ->select('userId')
                ->from(['{{%commerce_subscriptions}}'])
                ->distinct()
                ->all();

            // Create array of just user IDs
            $subscribedUserIds = array_column($subscribedUserIds, 'userId');

            return $subscribedUserIds;
       }
 }
```

I my case I needed to display all entries authored by users that are currently subscribed. In my template I used the variable like this:

```
{% set subscribedUserIds = craft.MyPlugin.allActivelySubscribedUserIds %}

{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .authorId(subscribedUserIds)
    .all()
%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not Commerce 2, but in Commerce 3, like this:

```
{% set userIdsWithSubscriptions = craft.subscriptions.limit(null).all()|group('userId')|keys %}
{% set users = craft.users.id(userIdsWithSubscriptions).all() %}

<ul>
  {% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user.username }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Via Nathaniel @ Craft Support (thanks!)

Comment: FYI: this may need some optimization, depending on the scale of your application, like selection of specific columns (`.select('userId').column()`, instead of `.all() | group('userId') | keys`), as loading all Element data + instantiating the models can quickly exhaust memory—we've seen major slowdowns after about 1K elements, and out-of-memory errors at 10K.

Comment: Thanks @AugustMiller that's good to add in. I am using a mixture of `.with` and pagination, but I think I may add in the `.select` too